# Google api maps and backbone error

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, backbone.js

This error compare when try to start function prova in my view:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Element' of undefined.
The error happens at line:var map= new google.maps.Map(document.get.Element.By.Id('pagina'),options);

```
        var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: Handlebars.compile(template),

 events: {
  "click .log_out":"log_out",
  "click .prove":"prove",
  'orientationchange' : 'onOrientationChange'
  },

  initialize: function() {

      console.log("inhomeview");

     this.render();



  },



    render: function() {
      //var context = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.model));//eliminare
      var context=this.model;
      var html =this.template(context);
      console.log(html);

       $('#pagina').empty();
       $('#pagina').append(this.$el.html(html));


      return this;
    },


    onOrientationChange: function() {
   if(window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) {
 //you are in landscape zone
 //do whatever you want to do
        }
    },












    log_out:function(){
        console.log("logout");
        Parse.User.logOut();
     //   new AppView;//ERRORE UNDEFINED NOT A FUNCTION
     window.location='index.html'  ;//METTERE UNA NEW APPVIEW MA DA ERRORE!!!
    },

    prove:function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(win);
    function win(pos){
        console.log("gps");
        var el='<div>'+ pos.coords.latitude+'</div>';
        el+='<div>'+ pos.coords.longitude+'</div>';
        el+='<div>'+ pos.timestamp+'</div>';
        $('#pagina').html(el);



    var lat=pos.coords.latitude;
    var lon=pos.coords.longitude;

    var options={

        center:new google.maps.LatLng(-34,150),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    };

      var html=$('#pagina');
      console.log(html);
    var map= new google.maps.Map(document.get.Element.By.Id('pagina'),options);// ERROR    HERE       


    };





    }


 });

 return HomeView;
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks incorrect:

```
document.get.Element.By.Id
```

I would expect:

```
document.getElementById
```

Which would explain the error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Element' of undefined.

Comment: ok perfect,now don't happens errors but nothing is painted on a page.

Comment: I suspect that is a different question. Perhaps your map DIV doesn't have a size?  Try looking through similar questions about backbone and Google Maps.